# SSH Connection refused after first connection on wi-fi

Tags: raspbian, ssh

After installing the Raspbian with NOOBS I was able to connect once to my Raspberry Pi model B3+. Now I am unable to connect again on port 22 with the following message:

> ssh: connect to host 192.168.178.125 port 22: Connection refused

Anyone knows why?

I am using MAC as a client.

Comment: Did you enable SSH and if you did: how exactly?

Comment: I enabled SSH by GUI. I found something: I need to give a static IP address config to Raspbian.

Comment: Static address is not really necessary. Have you tried using the hostname of the Pi? `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` (of course replacing 'raspberrypi' with the name of your Pi)

Comment: I added a static ip and now it is visible on the network. (sudo ip addr add 192.168.178.125/32 dev wlan0) Yes it works also with the hostname now. Before was not working. I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789947/raspberry-pi-no-ip-address

Comment: And is down again... I use an IP scanner (because pinging fails every time now) and is not visible in the network. The router seems to see it. What can be the problem?

Comment: when i execute this command: 'ip n s' i get the following message: 192.168.178.20 dev wlan0 FAILED. 192.168.178.20 is the Ip of the computer i try to connect with to raspbian. Anyone knows why it fails? 192.168.178.125 is the pi ip

Comment: @JohniDevo it would seem you've have posted two new questions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88746/raspberry-3b-invisible-on-wlan) and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88739/raspbian-not-visible-in-the-network-wifi-connected) that are essentially the same as this one. I have closed those questions as they are duplicates of this one. Since you are a new user please take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Raspberry Pi. Feel free to *edit* this question if you need to update it but please do not post it multiple times over. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @DarthVader is ok, it seems like i found the answer today, the problem was with the house router. Thanks for the Tour invitation, verby useful.

Comment: @JohniDevo instead of posting your solution in the question can you please post it as a separate answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the house router, i need to allow communication between devices on Wi-fi, now works smoothly fine.

```
robert-dan@Wolfram-mbp ~> ping 192.168.178.125
PING 192.168.178.125 (192.168.178.125): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.178.125: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.898 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.125: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.585 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.125: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.894 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.125: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.381 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.125: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=2.719 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.178.125: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2.166 ms
```